# When to use "include" and "including"?

Tags: differences, verbs, prepositions, word-usage

I know that *include* is a verb while *including* is a preposition but they made me confuse when it comes to their usage.

I usually confuse when to use *include* with *including*.

> - Most Thais like spicy food, (include/including) myself." (My guess is including)
> - Many Asians (include/including) Thais like to learn English." (My guess is including)
> - The price is (include/including) free-flow water." (My guess is include)
> - This book is (include/including) a free CD." (My guess is include)

Please give me an example of their usage.

Comment: _Include_ is a verb, so it never uses _is_; that means none of these work with _include_. _Including_ is a participle, so it can introduce a clause, like the first two; the last two should be _includes_ instead of _is include_.

Comment: Another difference between _(which) includes_ and _including_ is that the latter always implies an incomplete list.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>As a general rule, use the preposition *including* when you need a preposition that means (according to [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/including#Preposition)) “Such as, among which; introducing one or more parts of the group or topic just mentioned. [*Eg*]  ...fill in the details, including your name and address...”.</strike> (See *Edit 1*, below.)

Also as a general rule, use the verb *include* when you need a verb that means (again according to [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/include#Verb))  “To contain, as parts of a whole. [*Eg*]    The vacation package includes car rental”  or a verb that means “To bring into a group, class, set, or total as a (new) part or member.”  Examples of that last usage with the simple present and with the present participle include

> • Does the total include the rental fee?
>   • Are you including the rental fee in the total?

Regarding the examples in the question, the following forms are correct.  (The “is including” forms are clumsy and unlikely to be used by native speakers, but are not incorrect.)

> • Most Thais, including me, like spicy food.
>   • Many Asians, including Thais, like to learn English.
>   • The price is including free-flow water.
>   • The price includes free-flow water.
>   • This book includes a free CD.
>   • This book is including a free CD.

*Edit 1:* As Barrie noted, *including* is not a preposition.  Typically it serves as a present participle.  See the following extract from OED1 (1901) for some examples of use.

> **Including** *ppl. a.* [f. INCLUDE *v.* + -ING.]
>   1. That includes, shuts in, encloses, or comprises.
>   1670 G. H. *Hist. Cardinals* iii. iii. 329 If the Head of the including Faction, offers the Head of the Excluding Party, to assist him at any time, in the Election of one of the Excludents. 1843 MANNING *Serm.* (1848) I. xiv. 197 God has given him a moral sight to discern the right as the test, and as the including form of true expediency. 1899 *Edin. Rev.* Apr. 318 The including shafts were masked by ‘pans’ or depressions.
>   2. *Including* pres. pple. often governs a sb. particularizing a person or thing included in a group previously (or afterwards) mentioned; = Inclusive of.
>   Syntactically, it may sometimes be viewed as agreeing
>   with the word for the group, e. g. ‘I met a large party including your brothers’; but often it appears to agree with an indefinite pronoun *one, we, you* e. g. ‘including [ = if we, one, you include] servants, the party will number fourteen’. In the latter construction we have a kind of active of the passive absolute clause ‘servants being included’, or ‘if servants are included’.
>   1853 RUSKIN *Stones* Ven. II. vi, A large body of English
>   landscapists come into this class, including most clever
>   sketchers from nature. 1864 *Daily Tel*. 20 Sept., These
>   premises . . were . . in the occupation of several other warehousemen, including Mr. T. Tapling.

Comment: Wiktionary is wrong. _Including_ is never a preposition, any more than its near synonyms _containing_, _comprising_ and _embracing_ are. It is the _-ing_ form of the verb _include_, sometimes known as the present participle. Thus, _a free CD_ is not the complement of the preposition _including_, but the object of the non-finite verb _including_.

Comment: "This book is including a free CD." tells me that the book is currently performing an act of including.

Comment: @BarrieEngland, added edit 1